# How to merge column elements of combination results

Tags: r

I have 7 data frames with different row numbers but the same number of columns and I want to generate every possible combinations of all the data frames. I combined all the data frames in an array using:

```
Dataset <- array(list(), c(1,1,7))
Dataset[[1,1,1]] <- df1
Dataset[[1,1,2]] <- df2
Dataset[[1,1,3]] <- df3
Dataset[[1,1,4]] <- df4
Dataset[[1,1,5]] <- df5
Dataset[[1,1,6]] <- df6
Dataset[[1,1,7]] <- df7
```

I'm then able to generate the combinations using the combn() function:

```
comb1 <- combn(Dataset, 1)
comb2 <- combn(Dataset, 2)
...
comb7 <- combn(Dataset, 7)
```

comb2 for example will generate a 2 x 21 list matrix. How to merge every columns elements of the results of combn to a single data frame (1 x 21) in order to do some further processing on the new dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a list of data.frame

```
ll <-  lapply(1:7, function(i) do.call(rbind, combn(Dataset, i)))
```

and you can get a big data.frame

```
big.l <- do.call(rbind,ll)
```